# Copying data between dictionaries in Ansible

Tags: loops, dictionary

I have the following source data structure in a yml file:

```
animals:
  dogs:
    - { breed: "Golden Retriever", colour: "Golden" }
    - { breed: "Rottweiler", colour: "Black" }
    - { breed: "Labrador", colour: "Brown", "Black", "Cream" }
```

What I am trying to do is to open the file, loop through the data structure and copy it so I end up with an exact replica of the data.  Like so:

```
animals:
  dogs:
    - { breed: "Golden Retriever", colour: "Golden" }
    - { breed: "Rottweiler", colour: "Black" }
    - { breed: "Labrador", colour: "Brown", "Black", "Cream" } 

animals:
  dogs:
    - { breed: "Golden Retriever", colour: "Golden" }
    - { breed: "Rottweiler", colour: "Black" }
    - { breed: "Labrador", colour: "Brown", "Black", "Cream" }
```

What I also need is to be able to add and remove data from the source data source and when I re-run the playbook the copied data is updated too.

I have spent a bit of time looking at this and have got as far as this which is not much good as it doesn't give me what I want:

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:

    - name: Read the yaml
      slurp:
        path: ./animals.yml
      register: r_myfile

    - debug:
        var: r_myfile

    - name: Extract the data
      set_fact:
        mydata: "{{ r_myfile['content'] | b64decode | from_yaml }}"

    - debug:
        var: mydata

    - name: Populating the list of dictionaries in new dictionary
      blockinfile:
        dest: ./animals.yml
        block: "{{ mydata }}"
```

This is what the above playbook gives me:

```
animals:
  dogs:
    - { breed: "Golden Retriever", colour: "Golden" }
    - { breed: "Rottweiler", colour: "Black" }
    - { breed: "Labrador", colour: "Brown", "Black", "Cream" } 


# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
{'animals': {'dogs': [{'colour': 'Golden', 'breed': 'Golden Retriever'}, {'colour': 'Black', 'breed': 'Rottweiler'}, {'colour': 'Brown', 'breed': 'Labrador', 'Black': None, 'Cream': None}]}}
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So I have come up with the following solution in order to get us moving.  It required us to change the original data structure which wasn't much of an issue.

New data structure format in my yml file:

```
animals:
  dogs:
    - breed: "Golden Retriever" 
      colour: "Golden" 
    - breed: "Rottweiler" 
      colour: "Black"
    - breed: "Labrador" 
      colour: 
      - "Brown" 
      - "Black" 
      - "Cream"
```

This is how my new playbook looks:

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    - ./animals.yml
  vars:
    new_dict: "new_animals"
    new_item: "new_dogs"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: animals.dogs

    - name: Insert/Update data
      blockinfile:
        block: |
          {{ new_dict }}:
            {{ new_item }}:
              {{ animals.dogs | to_nice_yaml(width=80, indent=2) | indent(4) }}
        dest: ./animals.yml
```

The solution allows me to allocate a new name to the new dictionary and item as well as the ability to update the source data structure which will be picked up and applied to the new dictionary.

Hopefully this makes sense and if anyone has a better way of doing it please let me know.